# Choosing the correct datatype for storing locations

Tags: sql-server, database, sqlgeography

I am trying to figure out how I should store location data in a database.

Some articles I read recommend using the geography data type and others recommend geometry.

I would like to know what the difference is and why do both seem to require more params then only the longtitude and lattitude?

Any links to material to read (for those who are complete noobs) on the subject are welcome as well.

Comment: If latitude/longitude then use geography. Not only for points you can also save LineString, Polygon types as a single geography type. There are many reasons to use Geometry over Lat/Lng values, but totally depends on your requirements. Geometry has built in functions like Intersects, Distance etc which come in handy for calculations.

Comment: Also you get to use the Spatial Index of SQL server which increases the query performance of Spatial queries e.g Where point intersects a polygon

Comment: How would I know what to choose as SRID when using the function point to set a geography field? Beside that do you have any recommended reading material on this subject?

Comment: The SRID are used to identify the coordinate system, some providers restrict operations if the SRID is different for two spatial data types . e.g you can't compare 2 spatial types with different SRIDs in some providers, not sure about SQL Server. I tend to follow SRID == 4326 for all my spatial data types.
You can read about SRIDs on Wiki - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_reference_system
ArcGIS -
http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/using-sql-with-gdbs/what-is-an-srid.htm